# Task Layout panel not showing on the edit task page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

Im trying to modify some functionality in my task object.

I need to show a panel with a custom visualforce page on the edit task page, here is some of my code:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class TaskContactPanelController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
    public String JsonString {get; private set;}
    private Task a;

    public TaskContactPanelController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        this.a = (Task)controller.getRecord();
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Task" extensions="TaskContactPanelController">  
      test
</apex:page>
```

so i modify the layout of tasks, to include my custom page, it shows on the detail view, but its not showing on the edit page.

any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the page showing on the detail view (adding it to the layout only shows on the detail view).

What you can do is override the edit layout for the Task object (Setup->Customize Activities->Task Buttons, Links, and Actions) and select your visualforce page. The downside of doing this is that you won't get the standard edit layout showing anymore, you will need to re-build it in your VF page. Also, any changes in the standard layout will not be reflected in your page.